# CodeRush Xpress: disable the locator carets?

Tags: .net, coderush, coderush-xpress

I want to disable the "locator carets" put down by CodeRush when i execute one of it's commands, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[These may be the steps you're looking for:](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/54857/184769.aspx)

> Follow these steps to get to the
>   Markers options page:
>
> 1. From the DevExpress menu, select "Options...".
> 2. In the tree view on the left, navigate to this folder:
>
>    Editor\Navigation
> 3. Select the "Markers" options page. Here you can either disable Locator
>      Beacons or change the color to more
>      closely match your background color
>      (opacity appears to be hard-coded for
>      these).

Comment: I have it unchecked however it still draws them.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an option built into CodeRush. These small triangles in the code are called "markers", and they are used to help you get back to locations where you started a refactoring or consume-first declaration feature. So whenever you apply a refactoring or code provider that takes you away from where you started, one of these markers is dropped. Press Escape to collect the marker (go back to where you started). The options referred to in jasonh's answer affect the drawing of the locator beacons (which show you where the caret is being positioned - helpful if you have a large monitor). If you turned that off following Jason's advice, you might want to turn that back on. Note that the act of collecting a marker by pressing Escape, effectively removes that marker, so using Escape to return to previous locations will prevent markers from remaining inside your code.

Note that markers are not persisted, so if you have a file with existing markers and you want to clear them all, you can close and reopen that file.